# How to properly wrap a Jenkins plugin function such as copyArtifacts?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I have to wrap some Jenkins steps in dedicated functions, one of them is copyArtifacts

Here is some doc about this function, it list all of its parameters, but no default values for the optional parameters: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/

The usual way to call the copyArtifacts function is the following:

```
copyArtifacts projectName: "myJenkinsJob", filter: "*.pdf", excludes: "iAmUseless.pdf", flatten: false
```

One way to wrap it in a function while allowing for the same call syntax is the following:

```
void myCopyArtifacts(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
   ...
}
```

The fun part is to actually implement the wrapper. Since I cannot implement all the possible combination of arguments, I have to parse them manually one by one and give them a default value (which, in this case, I can find in the source code, but not always). And then call the plugin function.

This is not really practical, error prone, and not maintainable. Naively I thought that, because of the way groovy can receive Maps, the following would work:

```
void myCopyArtifacts(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
   currentWorkflowScript.copyArtifacts(parameters)
}
```

But it's not.

So is there a proper way to do it ?

For those wondering, if we are doing that it's for unit testing purposes with Mockito, we needed to wrap the functions to be mocked and at the same time we take the opportunity to limit and control the usages that can be done with them.

Comment: What kind of error do you receive when you do `currentWorkflowScript.copyArtifacts(parameters)`?

Comment: At least in a pipeline script this works: `def args = [label: 'foo', script: 'echo "bar"']; sh(args)`. So it actually is possible to call steps with a single map argument instead of individual arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This works if properly configured:

```
void myCopyArtifacts(Map params) {
   copyArtifacts projectName: params.projectName, 
                 filter: params.filter, 
                 excludes: params.excludes, 
                 flatten: params.flatten
}
```

You can then do either:

```
myCopyArtifacts projectName: "myJenkinsJob", 
                filter: "*.pdf", 
                excludes: "iAmUseless.pdf", 
                flatten: false,
                extra_parameter: "will not be used"
```

or

```
def myParams = [:]
myParams.projectName = "myJenkinsJob"
myParams.filter = "*.pdf"
// etc., finally
myCopyArtifacts(myParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) mentioned what I did, and explained, in my first post actually works perfectly. I will try to find the time to go back in my git history and find the error I encountered the first time but the correct answer for wrapping Jenkins steps is the following:

```
void myCopyArtifacts(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
   currentWorkflowScript.copyArtifacts(parameters)
}
```